# ADB Connection Error

Tags: android, adb

Im trying to run my android application using command prompt, once i run the adb status in command prompt is getting hang and the message "waiting for device" is getting display on the command prompt. Each and everytime i need to close the emulator and running the application. here is my logcat error. please help me friends.

```
[2012-12-28 15:48:49 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing
connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [2012-12-28 15:48:49
Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the device.] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
remote host     at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)     at
sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)    at
sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)  at
sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)  at
sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)   at
com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:395)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:462)   at
com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[2012-12-28 15:48:50 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that just Go to DDMS and there is a reset adb option, as in given Image below.[image: ADB]

You can restart adb manually from command prompt

run=>cmd=>path_android_sdk=>platform-tools>

Then write the below commands.

```
adb kill-server - To kill the server forcefully

adb start-server - To start the server
c:\android-sdk-windows latest\platform-tools>adb kill-server

c:\android-sdk-windows latest\platform-tools>

adb start-server
```

**daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037**

**daemon started successfully**

Comment: Hi, On my PC same issue raise, I fallow your step it solve my issue, But every time I have to do this again and again when I want to run app. Please suggest me any permanent solution for this.....Please......